# how can i change the array value from if else statement inside a loop?

Tags: php

i've been hours trying to assign value in the array but every iteration the array is set to 0 and i can't understand why , here's the code ...

```
$AurQ = array();
$prod = '';
while ($NOTIFY = $notification->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_r($AurQ);
    if ($NOTIFY['notification_type_ID'] == 1) {
        if (in_array($NOTIFY['qID'], $AurQ, true)) {
            echo "exist";
            continue;
        } else {
            $AurQ[] = $NOTIFY['qID']; // Adding the value to the array
            $prod .= '<li><a href="http://localhost/website/link/' . $NOTIFY['qID'] . '">    <span class="AskIcon"></span><span class="noti_announce">';
            $prod .= '<span class="unB">' . $NOTIFY['first_name'] . ' ' . $NOTIFY['last_name'] . '</span> ' . $NOTIFY['notify_name_en'] . ' "' . $NOTIFY['q_title'] . '"</span>';
            $prod .= '<span class="noti_time"><span class="icon"></span>' . time_elapsed_string($NOTIFY['time']) . '</span></a></li>';
        } // end of if doesn't exist in Array List
    } //end of if
} // end of loop
```

Comment: `var_dump($NOTIFY)` and check what is in it..

Comment: @b0s3 not working , the problem is the array is not assigned from inside the if statement ,,

Comment: `in_array($NOTIFY['qID'], $AurQ, true)` is always `false`.

Comment: var_dump($notification->fetch_assoc()) before the while loop and investigate the data

Comment: Do you have rows where `$NOTIFY['notification_type_ID'] == 1`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you're pushing a value to the array only after checking if it *already exists* in that array, which it doesn't given that you're initializing it as an empty array just above it.

So, there's a logic error here, and depending on what you're trying to do, it can be fixed by moving the `$AurQ[] = $NOTIFY['qID'] ;` line into the `else` statement, or by changing your if statement from `if (in_array($NOTIFY['qID'], $AurQ, true)) {` to `if (!in_array($NOTIFY['qID'], $AurQ, true)) {`.

As you didn't mention an issue with things displaying when you didn't want them to, I'm going to assume you're looking for the former solution as opposed to the latter. So, your code will wind up looking something like this:

```
$AurQ = array();
$prod ='';
while($NOTIFY = $notification->fetch_assoc()) {
if ($NOTIFY['notification_type_ID'] == 1) {
    if (in_array($NOTIFY['qID'], $AurQ, true)){ //If it's ALREADY in the array
        echo "exist";
        continue;
    } else { //Otherwise we need to add it, and display it
        $AurQ[] = $NOTIFY['qID'] ; // Adding the value to the array
        $prod .= '<li><a href="http://localhost/website/link/'.$NOTIFY['qID'].'">    <span class="AskIcon"></span><span class="noti_announce">';
        $prod .= '<span class="unB">'.$NOTIFY['first_name'].' '.$NOTIFY['last_name'].'</span> '.$NOTIFY['notify_name_en'].' "'.$NOTIFY['q_title'].'"</span>';
        $prod .= '<span class="noti_time"><span class="icon"></span>'.time_elapsed_string($NOTIFY['time']).'</span></a></li>';
    }// end of if doesn't exist in Array List

}//end of if
} // end of loop
```

Comment: yeah , i understand this , but no logical error , what's happening is if the array is empty , some data will appear and i will assign an id inside the array , while looping if the same id exist it will exit this iteration

Comment: Right but you're only adding it to the array if it's already there: it's never going to get added that way. If you move your `$AurQ[] = $NOTIFY['qID'] ;` line into the else statement, it should behave as you expect, because the code is now adding it to the array when it isn't already in it.

Comment: i've tried this
     still it echos the empty array list

Comment: where are you trying to echo the array contents?

Comment: at the beginning of the loop , after the start of every iteration

Comment: Can you update your code in the example to include the echo statement you're using to test this? The only reason this should be having problems is if the value of your `$NOTIFY` variable isn't what you're expecting it to be. EDIT: You did, thanks

Comment: i've redited the code up there so you can see what i'm talking about ,

Comment: and the value of $NOTIFY['qID'] = 5 , it works fine if i assigned the array immediately after the loop start , but that's not what i need :/

Comment: is the $prod variable properly getting filled with the expected content?

Comment: if the $prod variable is being properly filled, it means at least the snippet posted is working as intended. `$AurQ` is going to be empty for the first iteration of the loop, but it should start printing successively larger arrays containing the proper ID. Do you have any more context you can share?

Comment: i'm trying to make a simpler image for you

Comment: $AurQ = array();
$prod ='';
$i = 0;
$j =1;
while($i < 20) {
$i++;
print_r($AurQ); echo "</br>";
if ($j===1) {
if (in_array(5, $AurQ, true)){

    echo "exist </br>" ;
    continue;
} else {    
$AurQ[] = 5 ; // Adding the value to the array
echo "Array is set </br>";
}// end of if doesn't exist in Array List

}//end of if
} // end of loop

Comment: this sample is working fine , i guess i have something in my code i just can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Given your code you just need to move `$AurQ[] = $NOTIFY['qID'];` to else block.

Currently, `$AurQ[]` is empty and if block will never run because `in_array($NOTIFY['qID'], $AurQ, true)` will always return false.